# jexcel javascript spreedsheet get row number 1,2,3

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, spreadsheet

I have a table like this

```
<table class="jexcel" unselectable="yes" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">    
<thead class="draggable resizable">
<tr>
    <td class="jexcel_selectall"></td>
    <td data-x="0" style="text-align: center;" title="Model" class="">Model</td>
    <td data-x="1" style="text-align: center;" title="Price" class="">Price</td>
    <td data-x="2" style="text-align: center;" title="Model" class="">Model</td>
    <td data-x="3" style="text-align: center;" title="Cal" class="">Cal</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="draggable">
<tr data-y="0">
    <td data-y="0" class="jexcel_row">1</td>
    <td data-x="0" data-y="0" style="text-align: center; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow: hidden;">Mazda</td>
    <td data-x="1" data-y="0" style="text-align: center; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow: hidden;">2001</td>
    <td data-x="2" data-y="0" style="text-align: center; white-space: pre-wrap;">2000</td>
    <td data-x="3" data-y="0" style="text-align: center; overflow: hidden;"></td>
</tr>
<tr data-y="1">
    <td data-y="1" class="jexcel_row">2</td>
    <td data-x="0" data-y="1" style="text-align: center; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow: hidden;">Pegeout</td>
    <td data-x="1" data-y="1" style="text-align: center; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow: hidden;">2010</td>
    <td data-x="2" data-y="1" style="text-align: center; white-space: pre-wrap;">5000</td>
    <td data-x="3" data-y="1" style="text-align: center; overflow: hidden;"></td>
</tr>
<tr data-y="2">
    <td data-y="2" class="jexcel_row">3</td>
    <td data-x="0" data-y="2" style="text-align: center; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow: hidden;">Honda Fit</td>
    <td data-x="1" data-y="2" style="text-align: center; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow: hidden;">2009</td>
    <td data-x="2" data-y="2" style="text-align: center; white-space: pre-wrap;">3000</td>
    <td data-x="3" data-y="2" style="text-align: center; overflow: hidden;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

in Jexcel java-script spread sheet.
Now i want to get serial no 1,2,3
when i update the table

```
updateTable: function (instance, cell, col, row, val, label, cellName) {}
```

In the above update function i can get row starting from zeros
In each tr of data-y="0" i want to get inner html of jexcel_row using jquery or with this jexcel spread sheet plugin
[jexcel javascript spreadsheet](https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row data can be accessed using

```
instance.getData()[rowNumber]
```

The inner html of the row can be accessed using JQuery or Vanilla js

JQuery

```
$("tr[data-y='" + rowNumber+ "']")
```

Vanilla js

```
document.querySelector("[data-y='" + rowNumber + "'")
```